# HtmlGenericControl does not contain a definition for 'CssClass'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to show a validation message on click of a save button if the page has no errors, can anyone tell me why I'm unable to access the `CssClass` property of `validationMessage` in this instance?

```
<div id="validationMessage" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" class="hidden">
    Please fix any errors on the page before saving.
</div>


protected void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
    //stuff
    }
    else
    {
        validationMessage.CssClass = validationMessage.CssClass.Replace("hidden", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: `validationMessage.Attributes["class"] = validationMessage.Attributes["class"].Replace("hidden","");`

Comment: @JohnWu getting "cannot convert from string to int"